# Docker Nginx Proxy: how to route traffic

Tags: angular, spring, docker, nginx

I have a docker compose file. I run 3 containers (nginx, postgresql and java app)

All containers are create. My problem iswhen i want to acces to my app i use this url:
`http://10.34.18.2:81/myProject` but i have nothing.

What is wrong on my `conf` or my `yaml` file ?

***yaml file:***

```
version: '2'
services:
    nginx:
        image: 'nginx:latest'
        container_name: production_nginx
        volumes:
            - './nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
            - './nginx/error.log:/etc/nginx/error_log.log'
            - './nginx/cache/:/etc/nginx/cache'
        ports:
            - '81:80'
            - '444:443'
    myProject-postgresql:
        image: 'postgres:10.4'
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=myProject
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=myProject
        ports:
            - '5432:5432'
    myProject-app:
        image: myProject
        environment:
            - '_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m'
            - 'SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger'
            - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://myProject-postgresql:5432/myProject'
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10
        ports:
            - '8081:8080'
```

***nginx conf:***

```
server {

  listen 81 default_server;
  listen [::]:81 default_server;
  server_name localhost;

  location /myProject {
    proxy_pass http://10.34.18.2:8081/;
    rewrite ^/myProject(.*)$ $1 break;
  }
}
```

Comment: In your docker compose you have `81:80` which says from the host anything that comes in on port 81 will be routed to port `80` to the nginx docker container. In your nginx config you are saying to listen on port `81` not `80`. Also your proxy pass is wrong.

Comment: @ShawnC.  I have to change the port number but when i use this url `http://10.34.18.2:81/myProject` i have this message --> `This site is inaccessible`

Comment: Well, `10.34.18.2` is an internal docker network address which may or may not be your app but it for sure your app is running on `8080`. You should be doing `http://myProject-app:8080` so the container does a dns lookup to find your app.

Comment: @ShawnC. `10.34.18.2` is my server ip not an internal docker network adress

Comment: Your nginx container point to app? If yes, change in app ports to - 8080 and point nginx proxy to http://10.34.18.2:8080/

Comment: @Maksim yes my nginx container point to my app. I change my app port into my yaml file ?

Comment: Yes, change it in docker-compose. myProject-app: ports: - '8080', nginx config proxy_pass http://10.34.18.2:8080/;